# Webpack 3 Absolute Paths

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Can someone give me explicit directions on how to get absolute paths working with Webpack 3 in my React app? I can't seem to get it working. I'm using create-react-app if that helps and below is my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  // the directory that contains the entry files.
  context: __dirname,

  // The point points to enter the application.
  entry: './src/index.js',

  // path for the output bundle
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },

  // run webpack on all files with these extensions
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json'],
  },

  // webpack output stats
  stats: {
    colors: true,
    reasons: true,
    chunks: true,
  },

  // file loader rules
  module: {
    loaders: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/'),
    ],
    rules: [
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

What should I be putting in my webpack config and what should I be importing/requiring on my react js file?

Comment: I'm not understand your question, do you want to load an external file outside your src/ directory?

Comment: It's not clear where do you have problem with absolute paths. Absolute paths to what?

Comment: What I'm specifically trying to do is import an image from src/images/image.png. However, the js file I'm trying to import it into is nested very deeply in other directories so I have to do something like 'import ../../../../../../../path/to/image.png'. I want to set an absolute path so that I don't have to chain so many '../'

Comment: i think you should get friendly with aliases. I haven't used absolute paths with webpack, but aliases let you set up something similar.

Comment: I can't get aliases to work either :(